# Why are my Yesod tests so much slower in parallel?

Tags: haskell, ghc, yesod

On a machine with 8 virtual cores, `time .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/test/test +RTS -N1` reports:

```
real    0m10.368s
user    0m8.592s
sys 0m2.056s
```

While `time .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux/Cabal-1.22.5.0/build/test/test +RTS -N8` reports:

```
real    0m15.266s
user    0m40.032s
sys 0m19.880s
```

To reproduce: run `stack new partest yesod-simple`, add `replicateM_ 500` to `test/Handler/HomeSpec.hs` after `describe "Homepage"` and set `ghc-options` in `partest.cabal` to `-Wall -rtsopts -threaded`.

Why is this? ISTM that this should profit from parallelism - I can't think of any resources that the threads would fight for. `yesod-test` doesn't even spin up a real server. Removing the file upload from the test doesn't substantially affect the results.

This is a minimized example. My original problem is in a larger application where it seems like passing `-N` doesn't make the tests run in parallel at all. So my other question is: is there something in Yesod that prevents parallelism? Multiple threads accessing the DB at once would invalidate some tests, but I'd like to address that myself. (The `yesod-simple` template doesn't have a DB so that can't be the issue there.)

Comment: I don't know much about this, but I'm given to understand that you should generally only tell GHC the number of *actual* cores, not the number of hyperthreaded virtual ones. No, I don't know why.